# Alpha 0 vs Visible = false

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, tween

I'm developing a website in flash that has some animations (oh yeah) and I have a doubt about the way I got a better performance. Some of this animations got an alpha changing from 1 to 0. So there is two ways I did:

- Tweening, of course, but the objects remains on the stage with alpha = 0, is there some processing job remaining? Or Flash is smart and just ignore the object?
- Manually, and when alpha is below 0.1 I set visible = 0 and that's it. But I'm wondering if a tween is faster than a hand-made function...

Any opinions?

Comment: Setting visible to false is faster - that way all event listeners are ignored

Comment: Are you already tweening and just asking if setting the visible property is more efficient as part of the existing tween VS a loop/timer that is checking for alpha < .01?

Comment: Just an FYI, you should accept an answer that you feel best satisfies your question (if not satisfied please comment as to what else you'd like explained). Also good practice to upvote any answers that you felt were useful.

Answer (score 1):

Even when alpha is set to zero, Flash computes the display object on the display list.

Alpha determines opacity of a clip, whereas visible determines whether the clip is rendered by the player.

Therefore if you require no display or interaction, visible=false is higher performance.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the Greensock library.

To animate the alpha, then make it invisible, do this:

```
TweenLite.to(movieClip, 0.5, { autoAlpha: 0 });
```

More info about the Greensock Tweening engine:
http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

If you have too many objects on the display list and it effects the performance, you still can move your objects out of the "render" area, which (If I am correct) 2000px out of the stage, so then you should do this:

```
TweenLite.to(movieClip, 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0, onComplete: function() {
    movieClip.x = movieClip.y = 10000;
}});
```

I hope it helps,
Rob

Comment: If using TweenLite, you actually can just use the built in `autoAlpha` property in place of alpha. Then you don't have to make an onComplete function.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices, oh, I forgot about that, thanks for the heads up! I updated my answer. Cheers!

Comment: One thing about the greensock tweening libraries that I always like to mention when someone is encouraging someone else to use them: They do require you to purchase a license if used for any project that charges the end user to use the application you put them in.

Comment: Well, sometimes we got to pay for it. It's good to know about this library because if there is a lot of elements, can be handy to enhance the site performance. It seams there is no need (using TweenLite) to put the object away, with alpha 0, visible false is automatic.

Comment: @GustavoPinent - Agreed! I've used the Greensock engine for years for my ActionScript projects and the last couple of weeks I've been experimenting with the JavaScript version, they are pretty much identical and both awesome! The documentation of these libraries is very very useful and helpful, so digg in and enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

When an item has an `alpha` value of `0`,  it is still rendered by the player, still dispatches mouse/interaction events and still affects the bounds of it's parent.

When you set `visible` to `false`, an object is not rendered by the player per say, and does not dispatch mouse/interaction events.  It does however, still affect the bounds of the parent.

If you really want to be efficient, I'd recommend removing the item from the display list entirely.  eg. `removeChild(item);` then it no longer affects the bounds of the parent and is truly not rendered.

In regards to tweening, with any library it's pretty easy to set the visible to false when the tween is done or remove from the display list.  greensocks tweening library has a special parameter to do just that actually - instead of using the `alpha` property you use use `autoAlpha`. WHenever the value dips to zero, it sets the visibility to false. if goes above 0 it flips back to true.

Whether a tween is faster than a hand-made function depends on the quality of the tween and hand-made function.  Most tweening libraries are very efficient and I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Good points, I wasn't considering mouse and other interactions. Also visibility is used, in other cases, to test or not for collisions. It seams the classic tween is good for simple and localized objects, otherwise we got to code or buy some good library.