# Action Script random

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a project in which there will be three puzzle. When the user enter the game one of the puzzle will appear to him. In order to solve the puzzle he have to enter the write number in the input boxes. the problem is that each puzzle have different solution and i was not able to do the checking for which puzzle the random code chosen.

the time line

pass layer is where i placed the input boxes

layer 5 is Puzzle 1
game Two layer is puzzle 2
game Three layer is puzzle 3

[image]

this is the code before i added the random. Before i had each puzzle in different scenes. the code for checking if the input is correct

```
import flash.events.Event;
solved.visible=false;
txtOne.maxChars=1;
txtTwo.maxChars=1;
txtThree.maxChars=1;
txtFour.maxChars=1;
solved.visible=false;

txtOne.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);
txtTwo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);
txtThree.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);
txtFour.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);

function onClicks(e:Event): void{
if(txtOne.text=="2" && txtTwo.text=="4" && txtThree.text=="2" && txtFour.text=="8")
{
    solved.visible=true;
    gotoAndStop(2);

}

}
```

the same code i used for the other puzzles.

Then i combined them in same scene and did the random code 
/////////////
my code for the random

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();
var array1:Array=new Array(1, 2, 3);
Puzz_mc1.visible=false;
Puzz_mc2.visible=false;
Puzz_mc3.visible=false;
this["Puzz_mc"+array1[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]].visible=true;
```

//////////////
then i did this code to check if the answer is correct 
i said that first i need to check which puzzle is opened by the random code after that to check if the answer is correct or not. But this code did not work with me.

```
import flash.events.Event;
solved.visible=false;
txtOne.maxChars=1;
txtTwo.maxChars=1;
txtThree.maxChars=1;
txtFour.maxChars=1;
solved.visible=false;

txtOne.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);
txtTwo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);
txtThree.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);
txtFour.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onClicks);

function onClicks(e:Event): void{
    if(Puzz_mc1.visible==true)
    {

       if(txtOne.text=="2" && txtTwo.text=="4" && txtThree.text=="2" && txtFour.text=="8")
{
    solved.visible=true;
    gotoAndStop(2);

}
}
else if(Puzz_mc2.visible==true)
{
    if(txtOne.text=="5" && txtTwo.text=="2" && txtThree.text=="8" && txtFour.text=="2")
{
    solved.visible=true;
    gotoAndStop(2);

}
}
else if(Puzz_mc3.visible==true)
{
    if(txtOne.text=="2" && txtTwo.text=="0" && txtThree.text=="1" && txtFour.text=="4")
{
    solved.visible=true;
    gotoAndStop(2);

}
}

}
```

i have four input boxes.

first puzzle:
[image]

Second puzzle:
[image]

Third puzzle:
[image]

Input boxes for the all puzzle is the same:

I have a problem when i tried to enter anything in the boxes nothing is being entered

[image]

Comment: for the person who down voted my question. Could you give me explanation

Comment: The downvote is (probably) because your question isn't terribly clear.   So you have some text inputs,  and when you enter text into those text inputs no text shows up?  Is that the actual problem?   And if you take out the line of code with the `random()` it suddenly works again,  is that what you're saying?

Comment: the thing that i tried before is putting each puzzle in different scenes and tried the code for checking if the the input entered is correct or not. Then i wanted all the puzzles to be in one single scene. So i added the random code so that in each time i test the scene one of the three puzzle will come. Now when i wanted to check if the number entered the the input text is correct. i found that i can't enter anything in the boxes. So i don't where is the exact error because the program does not give me any errors. i will post the code i did before i try the random code.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis i updated the question

Comment: I'm still not clear on the actual problem.  Is the problem you can't put text into a text input, or that you're not sure how to check if the answer is correct?

Comment: At this point I would be curious to look at the fla file if you can save it for cs6 and have somewhere to upload it to

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis both of them. But i think the method i used to check if the answer is correct is the one that caused the other problem with the input text. Because before it was working well.

Comment: I think your problem is that the other puzzles are blocking your mouse clicks. If your other puzzles are on top of the puzzle. Rather than having all three invisible and setting their visibility, how about instantiating only the one that you are going to show. This would also greatly simplify your code as well. Look up addChild()

Comment: @C.Parcell -  non-visible objects are not interactive, meaning they will not block mouse clicks or other interactivity on objects behind them.   See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13313189/1457439

Comment: @GhezlanAL-Nofly - without seeing your fla file, I think it's going to be very difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis i can send it to your email or give a website that i can upload my file in.

Comment: I don't share my email, but feel free to post a link to it.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis this is the link https://files.fm/u/ajjsskkb#_ i uploaded two files. One is about this post named level3 and other is level2 i have similer problem but a little bit different if you could help me with it also. Thank you

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis  can you please help me out with it. the files are in this link https://files.fm/u/ajjsskkb#_

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
if(Puzz_mc1.visible=true)
```

you need to use `==` instead of `=`

```
if(Puzz_mc1.visible==true)
```

`=` is for assigning values to variables, whereas `==` is for comparing the values of variables.

Comment: I still have a problem when i tried to enter anything in the boxes nothing is being entered

Comment: I would assume that's an issue with how your stage is set up rather than the code here. Maybe the font size is too large to fit in the text box?

Comment: Maybe it's `maxChars=1` blocking new input?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the output console when you run it?

Comment: Does it start working again if you remove the `addEventListener` part?